# Is there a standard symbol for difference in order of magnitude?

Tags: notation

Is there a *standard notation*, symbol(s) or other shorthand for representing the *difference in order of magnitude* between two numbers? Given the function...

$$
f(x, y) = \log(x/y)
$$

So `f(1030, 55) ~= 1.272`.  Is there a standard notation to say "1030 is 1.272 orders of magnitude larger than 55"?  Would you just write...

$$
1030 \sim 55 \cdot 10^{1.272}
$$